# Tensorflow : Improve a Tensorflow model on false predictions loaded from checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow

After training a network and out-putting a model, is it possible to feed single false predictions into the network after loading the first model from a checkpoint to help improve performance.

The current solutions I have tried so far have involved:

```
    with tf.Session() as sess:


        #Try new method...
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./model2.ckpt.meta')
        saver.restore(sess, './model2.ckpt')
        graph = tf.get_default_graph()

        x_1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("x:0")
        y_1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("y_:0")
        train_step = graph.get_tensor_by_name("train_step:0")

        trX = image
        trY = np.eye(10)[digit]

        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: trX, y_: [trY],
                            keep_prob:0.5})

        new_saver = tf.train.Saver()
        new_saver.save(sess, "./model2.ckpt")
        sess.close()

        trX = image
        trY = np.eye(10)[digit]

        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: trX, y_: [trY],
                            keep_prob:0.5})
```

Or this solution:

```
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.restore(sess, "./model2.ckpt")

        trX = image
        trY = np.eye(10)[digit]

        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: trX, y_: [trY],
                            keep_prob:0.5})
```

Both have resulted in the network loosing the ability to correctly predict a previously image, that was being predicted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was with the training step, not the restoring of the weights. After loading the weights and running the training step the weights were showing NAN for every value. This issue was resolved by clipping the values in the cross entropy function.

The original cross entropy function was: 
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y_conv))

Which was changed into:
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(y_conv,1e-10,1.0)))